# module not found error: mybinder interactive notebooks

Tags: python, github, conda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create an interactive notebook using mybinder.org. These are the steps I am taking:

Step 1: upload the notebook in github [github link to the simplistic notebook](https://github.com/NaserNikandish/testrepo/blob/main/test01.ipynb)

Step 2: create an environment.txt file using `pip freeze > requirement.txt` and upload it in the same repo. [link to the requirement.txt file](https://github.com/NaserNikandish/testrepo/blob/main/requirement.txt)

Step 3: render the notebook on mybinder.org. [link to the rendered notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/NaserNikandish/testrepo/main?filepath=test01.ipynb)

Once the notebook is loaded, it fails to import any of the numpy or pandas libraries. I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy. Here is the image of the errors:

[image: Error message]

What am I doing wrong? Any hints is really appreciated; I have been on this for a while... if it helps at all, I prepare my notebooks using JupyterLab.

Comment: In the menu click on kernel > change kernel and select the virtual env that you want to use.

Comment: Can you post the output of this `import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.version); print(sys.version_info)` ? Is this is right python version you want to use ?

Comment: @JayPatel: Absolutely. Here is the otput: 
```C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\python.exe
3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)```

Comment: @Walid: Thank you for your comment. That didn't solve the issue. There is no virtual env option under Kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax here really matters. The configuration file you are trying to make should be named `requirements.txt` in order to be recognized by Binder. [Yours is named incorrectly `requirement.txt`](https://github.com/NaserNikandish/testrepo/tree/2deb2e2a059ce5e85e5a9f795dd8c1b7c3b768a5).

In the future, you can start a repo perhaps more easily by going to the pertinent example ['Python environment with a requirements.txt' here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and pressing the green `Use this template` here button in the upper right side of the screen. Similarly, you can use [all the other examples](https://github.com/binder-examples) as templates as well. The purpose and roles of these examples are expanded on [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sample_repos.html).